# Dotnetnuke content staging update count keeps growing by time

Tags: dotnetnuke

After I set up the content staging with exact copy of live site, I changed the modules the workflow settings sitewide. Now the count of module updates available keep growing for the past 12 hours. Is there something wrong?

Comment: IMHO content staging in DotNetNuke doesn't really work (this is my personal opinion only)

Answer (score 0):

Just confirm your modules workflow settings will update the module settings update time stamp, ie, is it your workflow settings acts like module settings update, than the content staging consider as module update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There were lot of inconsistencies with both environment. Once i fixed that, it worked. But currently stopped using CS as it has many other issues. I think DNN content staging is not mature for production environment yet. IMO.